# $ax+by=cx+dy$, where $x$ and $y$ are variables. Does $a=c$, $b=d$?

Tags: polynomials

If I have the equation $ax+by=cx+dy$, where $x$ and $y$ are variables and $a,b,c,d$ are coeficients. And also this equation holds for all $x$ and $y$. Can we conclude from this equation that $a=c$ and $b=d$? If we can, is there some theorem about that or proof?

Comment: If the given equality holds for all real $x$ and $y$ we can make the suggested conclusion (comparison of coefficients).

Comment: @Peter Yes, holds for all x and y (I added edition to the post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it holds for all values of $x,y$ then it holds for $x =1; y = 0$ and for $x=0; y=1$.

So $a*1 + b*0 = c*1 + d*0$ and $a*0 + b*1 = c*0 + d*1$.

Answer (score 1):

write your equation in the form
$$x(a-c)=y(d-b)$$ if this is fulfilled for all real $x,y$ then it must be $$a=c$$ and $$b=d$$

Answer (score 0):

If this equation needs to be hold for arbitrary $x$ and $y$, then it is a ‘YES’; otherwise it is a ‘NO’